# S3 says secure however I can read contents without any keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I'm trying to securely store my production keys in an S3 Bucket and have the EC2 load them.
Here's what it looks like. It's saying `Bucket and objects not public`.

[image]

So I proceed to enter this code to retrieve the bucket information.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3(); // Pass in opts to S3 if necessary

var getParams = {
  Bucket: 'secret-bucket-name', // your bucket name,
  Key: 'keys-temp.js' // path to the object you're looking for
}

s3.getObject(getParams, function(err, data) {
  // Handle any error and exit
  if (err){
    console.log("err",err);
    return err;
  }

  // No error happened
  // Convert Body from a Buffer to a String

  let objectData = data.Body.toString('utf-8'); // Use the encoding necessary
  console.log("objectData",objectData);
});
```

And everything works smoothly. It grabs the keys no problem. Only, this is on my local server not my AWS server. Is this not exposing my keys to the public?

Is this the right way to go about saving production keys? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There is no fundamental insecurity in Amazon S3. You need to look in your local environment for credentials that the SDK is picking up and using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the right way to go about saving production keys? Or am I missing something?

Its rather a **bad practice** to keep any keys/secrets in S3. The better way is to use AWS dedicated services for that. The services are:

- [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) with `SecureString` parameter type.
- [AWS Secrets Manger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html)

You can have fine grain control over the secrets using IAM policies as well as resource-based policies for Advanced Parameter Store's parameters. For example, to use the secrets on your EC2 instance, it would  have **IAM instance role** attached with **fine grain permissions** to access the secrets.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes it a bad practice?

Comment: @TrevorWood Hi. for once, its easy to make such bucket objects public - just one mouse click and your secrets are open to the public. Seconds, its difficult to access them - always have to download the object first, before you can read its content, meaning you can forgot to delete it after use. Once the secret file is downloaded, there are no controls of who/what can access it. Third, no support for rotation of keys. There are more reasons why AWS decided to create dedicated services specifically designed to keep secrets there, not in S3.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've checked out AWS Secrets Manager but at .40 cents per secret it seems expensive. I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to run my app. I wonder if just storing keys in the environment variables would be okay?

Comment: Regular Parameter Store is free. I can't definitely answer that sadly. It depends how "sercret" are these secrets? Is their security of uttermost importance or not? Only you know that as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into it. I've stumbled across a few topics about storing passwords. namely this one. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html#rds-external-credentials . This one suggests storing database passwords into the environment variables. It also says "for more security store it in S3". By "more security" do you know if it means other developers? I assume if it's saying to store passwords in the environment variables it should mean they're safe from public view

Comment: @TrevorWood Yes, they won't be public. Only accessible to your application and anyone who has access to the EB console or CLI/SDK. Normally, for better security you would put secret names (e.g. a reference to a parameter in a iparameter store) in the EB env variable, and then retrieve the secret on the instance. This way you also protect the secrets from anyone who has access to the EB console.

Comment: @TrevorWood No problem. Glad could help :-)